# Display OSGB (EPSG: 27700) ArcGIS tile MapServer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: arcgis-server, openlayers, tiles

I am trying to add this ArcGIS OS Open Background map service in OpenLayers 3.7.0.

http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Background_2/MapServer

I set the projection and the resolutions for this service in my OL setup like so:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:27700', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs');

ol.proj.get("EPSG:27700").setExtent([0, 0, 700000, 1300000]);

var layerOSGBtiles = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
        url: 'http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Background_2/MapServer',
        projection: 'EPSG:27700'
    })
});

var view = new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:27700',
    center: [300000, 500000],
    extent: [0, 0, 700000, 1300000],
    resolutions: [132291.9312505292, 66145.9656252646, 26458.386250105836, 19843.789687579378, 13229.193125052918, 6614.596562526459, 2645.8386250105837, 1322.9193125052918, 661.4596562526459, 264.5838625010584, 132.2919312505292, 66.1459656252646, 26.458386250105836, 19.843789687579378, 13.229193125052918, 6.614596562526459, 2.6458386250105836, 1.3229193125052918, 0.6614596562526459],
    zoom: 6
});

map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: [],
    layers: [layerOSGBtiles],
    view: view
});
```

So far I have been unable to get any love from TileArcGISRest. Any help will be welcome.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/r0kqdwan/) is a JSFiddle which shows the right coordinates and a control geometry for the outline of the British Isles.

Comment: When viewing this service in ArcGIS the requests to the tile server are of them form MapServer/tile/12/551/822 which returns the tile (level, row, column), whereas debugging your jsfiddle OL3 is sending what look more like a WMS GetMap request for each tile. 

I'd check the constructosr for layerOSGBtiles as it seems OL3 thinks is treating the layer as a WMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArcGIS Tiled Map Services can be added using the [ol.source.XYZ](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/xyz-esri.html) constructor, dropping this in for layerOSGBTiles does display some tiles.  As the OSGB map services use a different tiling scheme this should also be specified using a [tileGrid](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html).

```
var resolutions = [132291.9312505292, 66145.9656252646, 26458.386250105836, 19843.789687579378, 13229.193125052918, 6614.596562526459, 2645.8386250105837, 1322.9193125052918, 661.4596562526459, 264.5838625010584, 132.2919312505292, 66.1459656252646, 26.458386250105836, 19.843789687579378, 13.229193125052918, 6.614596562526459, 2.6458386250105836, 1.3229193125052918, 0.6614596562526459];

var tilegrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
    resolutions: resolutions,
    origin: [-5220400,4470200]
})
var layerOSGBtiles = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/qHLhLQrcvEnxjtPr/arcgis/rest/services/OS_Open_Background_2/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        projection: 'EPSG:27700',
        tileGrid: tilegrid
    })
});
```

Comment: Ok, that's encouraging to see the tiles at least. Not really sure how to add an origin into the schema. I have updated the jsfiddle with your code snippet.

Comment: Hi Dennis - yes sorry not been able to produce a full example, but I did try with [TileGrid](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html) so that might help, we had to do something similar with leaflet and proj4js.

Comment: Boom. TileGrid did the trick. I updated the jsfiddle which is now working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's great @DennisBauszus - glad you got it working in the end :) 
I've added your solution to the answer.